# GORM Composite mapping not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm, composite-key

On grails 2.4.3 and postgresql as the database I have:

```
class ClassA {
    Set classB = []

    static belongsTo = [classC: ClassC]
    static hasMany = [classB: ClassB]
}
```

and:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
class ClassB implements Serializable {

    ClassA classA
    Integer number

    static belongsTo = [classA: ClassA]

    static mapping = {
    id composite: ['number', 'classA']
}
```

And I'm getting this weird error:

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener - Error initializin  
the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':   
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is  
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting 
bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NullPointerException Message: Error creating bean with name 
'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting 
bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NullPointerException Line | Method ->> 266 | run in 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - | 1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor | 617 | 
run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^ 745 | run in 
java.lang.Thread
```

What is going on? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

not sure, what the message means, but this is wrong:

```
Set ClassB = []
```

it should be

```
Set<ClassB> classB = new HashSet<>()
```

UPDATE:

see [the refdoc](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#compositePrimaryKeys). the fields should be of primitive types I'd say.

try converting extracting a property out of the ClassB instance:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
class ClassB implements Serializable {

  ClassA classA
  String someAProp
  Integer number

  void setClassA( ClassA a ){
    classA = a
    someAProp = a.someProp
  }

  static belongsTo = [classA: ClassA]

  static mapping = {
    id composite: ['number', 'someAProp']
  }
 }
```

Comment: wrote it wrong on the question, I was ok on the actual code, it is not the problem.

Comment: try applying `@EqualsAndHashCode` to ClassA as well

Comment: Same thing, with and without 'implements Serializable'

Comment: Thanks for the help man, but still giving me the  same cryptic error.

Comment: try excluding the domain-classes one-by-one to "triangulate" the problem. Perhaps it's located somewhere else >)

Comment: I dont know what you mean with triangulate.

Comment: remove one domain-class and comment out references to it. build and run the app, see if the exception remains. if it does, repeat it with another class and so on

Comment: Commenting the id composite line alone throws no exception, the problem is in the composite for sure.